# Where does this angular momentum equation come from? (particle sliding inside of cone)

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, angular-momentum

I was reading a paper on a particle sliding on the inside of a conical surface (https://arxiv.org/abs/nlin/0204019) and I understood it until they said:

> $mr^2\dot{\theta}\sin^2\phi_0=L_z$
>
> This dynamical constant, $L_z$, is the **vertical component of the angular momentum**.

(page 6)

They don't clarify this any further. I understand where the equation comes from and the fact that it is constant, but why exactly is it the vertical component of angular momentum? I can see that $mr^2\dot{\theta}$ is $|\vec{{L}}|$, but why is its product with $\sin^2\phi_0$ ($\phi_0$ is a constant, the angle between vertical and cone's slant) the vertical component of its magnitude?

Comment: The authors should say about what point they are taking the angular momentum.

Comment: I think you'll get this value of $L_z$  if (a) you take the angular momentum about the cone vertex, and (b) take $r$ to be the 'slant' length along the cone surface from the vertex to the particle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting $L_{\rm z}= mr^2\dot{\theta}\sin^2\phi_0$ as $L_{\rm z} = m(r\sin\phi_0)^2\,\dot{\theta}$ illustrates that the author is using the horizontal component of $r$ to evaluate the angular momentum.

Comment: Thank you. But with this angular momentum in the $z$-direction equation, how can I put a number to this? I see that it is a constant, so I would compute the angular momentum at time 0 and I know that it will remain that value at all times, but what can I intuitively input for $\dot{\theta}$ at the beginning of the particle's motion around the cone? How do I know what that is?